# Trying to Dynamically change background video as user scrolls

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a single page website with a video background that changes video URL or source as you scroll farther and farther down. I was messing around with window.onScroll but it doesn't seem to dynamically check the scroll position at each instance? As of now I am testing with two videos. When I scroll 200 pixels in or more, I want it to be the video of the ocean, Otherwise play the night street lights video. When I begin to scroll it imediately goes to night street lights (which makes sense) then as I pass 200 it does not switch over to the other video, however if I refresh at that spot or higher in it will show the ocean video. Am i doing something wrong or is there another way to go about this? I am trying to mimick this example I saw with background color changes [HERE](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onscroll2) and here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BigKahuna13/o4fzkd1v/7/) for what I have tried to do. I've been running in circles with this and it would great if I can get pushed towards the right direction or get some clarity.

```js
 var video = document.getElementById('video-background');
    var source = document.createElement('source');
  

  window.onscroll = function(){
     if (document.body.scrollTop > 200 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 200) {
       source.setAttribute('src', 'https://storage.googleapis.com/coverr-main/mp4/The-Slow-Dock.mp4');
      
      video.appendChild(source);
      video.play();
          } 
      else{
        source.setAttribute('src', 'https://storage.googleapis.com/coverr-main/mp4/Night-Traffic.mp4');
        
        video.appendChild(source);
        video.play();
       }
```

```css
.section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
body{
  height: 500px;
}

.video-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>

    <div class="section">

        <h1>1</h1>

        <div class="video-container">
            
            <video autoplay loop id="video-background" muted></video>
        </div>
           
 
  </div>     
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just change the video.src property for changing video instead of creating a new video source eachtime , but your main issue was because you were using "document.body.scrollTop" it was not changing I have edited the code

HTML

```
<div class="section">

        <h1>1</h1>

        <div class="video-container">

            <video autoplay loop id="video-background" muted autoplay></video>
        </div>


  </div>
```

JS file

```
var video = document.getElementById('video-background');
  var source = document.createElement('source');
    window.onscroll = function() {

     if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 200) {   
     if(video.src !== 'https://storage.googleapis.com/coverr-main/mp4/The-Slow-Dock.mp4'){
      video.src='https://storage.googleapis.com/coverr-main/mp4/The-Slow-Dock.mp4';
      }

          } 
      else{
       if(video.src !== 'https://storage.googleapis.com/coverr-main/mp4/Night-Traffic.mp4')
        video.src='https://storage.googleapis.com/coverr-main/mp4/Night-Traffic.mp4';

       }




        };
```

This is the fiddler attached https://jsfiddle.net/qtrfj3ks/4/

Comment: Every time i scroll the video disapears, I don't see this working to well on my end, any thoughts?

Comment: @DaveValles I have made the changes in javascript file , you can have a look

Comment: This is perfect! makes a lot more sense now thank you so much!!